# How would I create a form field where only numbers between 1-10 can be entered?

Tags: html

So I would like to create a form field where the user is only able to input numbers between 1-10, and I would like it to show an error upon submission if the user enters any number bigger than that.

I know I need to use the title tag for the error, and pattern tag for it however what expressions would I use for the pattern tag?

Comment: I'll just give you the five words to send to google, in case you have not searched in that particular way: `limit input field values html`. For me the first result gives the solution.

Comment: you need to use javascript,

Comment: I am not sure what is allowed - only digits 0-9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`<input type="number" min="1" max="10">`

with html5 min and max attributes you can restrict the value of some input fields like dates and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 validation by adding required attribute alongside with min and max:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" max="10" min="1" required />
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

[The required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute)

Answer (score 0):

This solution has a bit of JavaScript code, and works also with no HTML5 compliant browsers 
(older and new one).

```js
var widget = document.querySelector('input[name="onlyDigits"]');
widget.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="onlyDigits" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="">
  Num 1-10:<br>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10" required />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```